# Replacing characters from a String List in python

Tags: python

So i have a problem where i need to replace a character from a string in an array of strings by providing an x and a y coordinate. In this case, the output should be, that the second "0b000000" has a "1" instead of a "b".  However, it either replaces all "b"s in that array, or doesn't replace anything. Here's my code, any help is appreciated:

```
def setpixel(x, y):

    byte_array = [
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000",
            "0b000000"
    ]


    line = byte_array[y - 1]
    element = line[x - 1]

    line.replace(element, "1")

    print(byte_array)



 setpixel(2, 2)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. What did you expect `line.replace` to do?

Comment: Also, each time you call the function, you redefine the array, so there wouldnt be any persistent change

Comment: `line.replace` **returns a new** string. It does not change a string in-place because string characters cannot be altered (strings are therefore immutable; they cannot be mutated)

Comment: Didn't realize it doesn't change the original String. With the answer below it finally works, thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
byte_array[y - 1] = line.replace(element, "1")
```

to actually use the return value of `str.replace` and make the list reflect that change. But if the element at that pixel happens to occur more than once in that string, this will not work reliably. The safest:

```
byte_array[y - 1] = line[:x-1] + "1" + line[x:]
```

And btw, if you are serious about coding, you should get used to 0-indexing! Everything will make so much sense ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it, you really helped me!